# \phantomsection - how to jump to the chapter title instead of the center of the page (only)

Tags: hyperref, positioning, links

I use `\phantomsection` in my document, because I have nonnumbered chapters in Table of Contents:

```
\chapter*{Chapter title}    
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter title}
```

Command `\phantomsection` doesn’t work correctly - jumps properly to page, but the center of the page, not on the top. View as a pdf is 'fit to horizontal' so I cannot see '*Chapter title*' without scrolling through the page. Command `\chapter{}` works fine.

Comment: Welcome! `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\chapter*{Chapter Title}`. If you use a KOMA class you can use `\addchap`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\phantomsection` sets the label at the current position. However the command `chapter` has previous and and skip below the title. Based on the last skip the position of `\phantomsection` is specified. To provide the label at the top of the page use the following order:

```
\cleardoublepage%\clearpage in onside mode
\phantomsection
\chapter*{Chapter Title}
```

If you use a KOMA class you can also use the command `\addchap` which simplefy the the lines above to

```
\addchap{Chapter Title}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

% \makeatletter% <-- another useful trick
% \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{}
% \makeatother%

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}

Text.

\newpage
\section{First Section}

Text.

\newpage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% must reset if you want to bring numbering back
\chapter{Second Chapter} 
\section{Another First Section}

More text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: One has to remember to reset `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth` afterwards, if the unnumbered chapter is not the last.

Comment: Your changing doesn't work. `tocdepth` must be changed in the preamble or by `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- well, it works for me when I do it.  Have you tried the example? EDIT: oh! you are referring to the `tocdepth`.  True, and that part should be taken out since it doesn't have anything to do with the question....

Comment: @jon: lol -- have fun