# Hyperref link jumps to the first entry of the bibliography entry rather than to its title

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, hyperref, links, etoolbox

This is a follow-up question to Gonzalo Medina's answer of [Bibliography in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71129/16865). One of his solutions for including the bibliography in the ToC is to use the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\csname phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{toc} {chapter}{\bibname}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

With `hyperref`, however, clicking on the ToC entry for the bibliography you end up at the first bib entry rather than at the title of the bib as it should be. How can this be solved?

PS: This is not a duplicate of [\phantomsection - how to jump to the chapter title instead of the center of the page (only)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56521/16865). I tried playing around with `\cleardoublepage` (as suggested in the answer to that question) but it didn't work for my problem.

Comment: Actually my question IS almost a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56521/16865 In my answer you can see why. Does anyone suggest that my question should either be closed or flagged as exact duplicate? @moderators: If so please feel free to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Inserting `cleardoublepage` between `\csname` and `phantomsection` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\csname cleardoublepage phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{toc} {chapter}{\bibname}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```