# My table of content links to wrong pages

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Please find below a snapshot of my Table Of Content page. When I click on links to pages ii, v, vi, and vii, the first page (title page) shows up. But the links for chapter pages work correctly. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please find a minimal-example here. Please download the three files in this link into a folder and run the .tex file.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5F4rN4CU4nUflhIdU91UElHRGRxRmFmeWR0V3hhbG5rMHR5NGx3Z1d2MjgyUEpxUVdHdGM&usp=sharing

Comment: try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-to-invoke-phantomsection or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56521/phantomsection-how-to-jump-to-the-chapter-title-instead-of-the-center-of-the may be all what you need is to update your hyperref package.

Comment: touhami:
As "Dedication" and other sections before "Chapters" are created automatically, and not by me, so I cannot add \phantomsection to those sections. Therefore, the solutions suggested in the two links could not help me. Thank you though!

Comment: I don't see why not. The definition for the dedication page is on line 115 of your .sty file. The definition for the list of figures is on line 195, etc.

Comment: I see what you mean Mike,

It is the part for my figures, for example:
      \def\listoffigures{%
      \newpage
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
        \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
       \hbox{ }
      \twoinmar
      \centerline{\large\bf LIST OF FIGURES}
      \vspace{0.7in}
      \begin{doublespace}
      \@starttoc{lof}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
      \addtocontents{lof}{\noindent\underline{\bf    Figure}\hfill\rm\protect\newline}
       \end{doublespace}
      \pagestyle {empty}
    }

How should I change this?

Comment: what about updating hyperref?

Comment: Add the `\phantomsection` command before the `\addcontentsline` command, as given in the first linked answer.

Comment: Thank you Mike. It worked.
I also thank you Touhami for suggesting me to use \phantomsection.